# Modulus of complex exponential function

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm going through some notes trying to understand them and in an integral function in a section on complex integration along a path it uses a modulus to find path length, but one of the steps makes no sense to me, can someone please explain why:

$\int |ie^{it}|dt= \int 0 dt$

Thank you

Comment: Is there some context missing? Is $t$ a real number? If it is, you have that $|i e^{it}| = |i|\cdot |e^{it}| = 1\cdot 1 = 1.$

Comment: It's wrong: $ |i\,e^{it}|=1$ for any $t$ real. In any case $ |i\,e^{it}|>0$ for any $t$ complex

Answer (score 0):

When $\text{t}\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\left|ie^{\text{t}i}\right|=\left|\left(\cos\left(\text{t}\right)+\sin\left(\text{t}\right)i\right)i\right|=\left|\cos\left(\text{t}\right)i-\sin\left(\text{t}\right)\right|=\sqrt{\cos^2\left(\text{t}\right)+\left(-\sin\left(\text{t}\right)\right)^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$$